# can wily monitor grails application?

Tags: grails

Our enterprise uses  CA Wily Introscope for production live environment. We want to develop an application using GRAILS, but I could not find any documentation on web/stackoverflow regarding this. Has anyone has done this? Is this possible? Else we may have to go back to doing in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It can be done quite easily. We do that in our enterprise, Grails is after all java under the hood running on the JVM and Wily has no issues dealing with that.